# converting byte to image in sql server using vb.net 2010

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, image

i have my code here for converting **binary to image** from an `sql` using `vb.net 2010`. But every time i run this code get a error `IndexOutOfRangeException` was Unhandled

all answers are appriciated thanks

```
 Dim strDiagram As String = "SELECT DiagramImage FROM [" + strDBLeads + "].dbo. QuoDiagram WHERE QuotationID =" + intQuotationID.ToString
 Dim lb() As Byte = lrd("DiagramImage")
 Dim lstr As New System.IO.MemoryStream(lb)
 PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(lstr)
```

Comment: What is `lrd` variable?

Comment: And what is the length of the image you select from the database?

Comment: the lrd is the line reader of the database and Im really new to sql ang I dont know how to get the lenght of the image also Im getting a out of memory exception

Comment: You can check the length by running this query `select DATALENGTH(DiagramImage) from QuoDiagram`